# returning rows from $wpdb - losing my mind

Tags: php, wordpress

spent the last two hours trying to get this $wpdb->get_results to return an array the same way while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  would.  I have tried everything, get_col, get_row, etc... went through the wp codex and tried all their examples and literally nothing works.  Everything returns either Array ( ) or NULL.  I am losing my mind here, any help is GREATLY appreciated.

I originally coded this plugin in PDO and then realized wordpress doesn't support that.  I am not a fan of wpdb sql.  Here it is;

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = '$userid'");
foreach ($query as $row) {
echo $row->date;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using this code? Stand-alone, plugin, theme? What function, hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you must have crossed by this in http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb :

> One of three pre-defined constants. Defaults to OBJECT.
>
> - OBJECT - result will be output as an object.
> - ARRAY_A - result will be output as an associative array.
> - ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array.

You can make your code as follows :

```
$result_array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = '$userid'", ARRAY_A);
foreach( $result_array as $key -> $value ) {
    echo "Key = " . $key  . "<br />";       // outputs field name
    echo "Value = " . $value . "<br />";    // outputs the value
}
```

Don't forget to esacpe all your inputs using `$wpdb->prepare()` 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: I used your code, and it no longer gives me errors.  But it does tell me ' Creating default object from empty value in... '   This makes no sense, because the table has rows in it.

Comment: I changed it to foreach ($result_array as $row) and it is finally functioning.  I read in the codex to call like this ' $row->date ' but it only functions like this ' $row['date'] '.

Comment: Well, you should use $row->date if you choose the result to be an object (the default option). If you choose the result to be an associative array then you should use $row['date'] . But I don't know why it gave you that error.(Execuse my english)

Answer (score 1):

First of all to use `wpdb` class in plugins you need to include `wp-blog-header.php` in  the start or `wp-load.php`

And then you would need to define the wpdb as global to access all its functions

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = '$userid'");
```

Make sure you included the right path for the above mentioned files

If you want to get the results as an array you would need to pass the second argument in your query as `ARRAY_A or ARRAY_N`

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = '$userid'",ARRAY_N);
```

Bydefault it is set to return `OBJECT`

Comment: Still nothing!  

$your_db_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'jo_plugin_options';
global $wpdb;

$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$your_db_name} WHERE user_id = {$userid}",ARRAY_N);

returns  array(0) { }

Comment: And when you run this query in phpmyadmin then you got results ? try to echo your query

Comment: If you're including `wp-blog-header` or `wp-load` in a *plugin*, you're `doing_it_wrong()`, very wrong...

Comment: I did include the blog_header since djanuj suggested it.